# Dynamic reference to line number in the code (Netbeans)

Tags: php, netbeans

Is it possible in NetBeans to tag a line of (e.g. PHP) code and refer to this line number dynamically?, like

```
echo "check the line number <tagged_line_number> in the script";
```

Problem is that with code development any line can change a number naturally, so static reference does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking the PHP solution, use [**LINE** constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for that.

Comment: It would give me a current line number - not the "tagged" one which I need to refer to. 
I believe it must be a IDE's (Netbeans in this case) feature that would on code compilation would "magically" convert the tag to number.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [Vladislav`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33437574/3810453) is the correct one.
You definitely could use [LINE constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) like so:

```
$line = __LINE__ + 1; // use this right before the line you want to tag
// tagged line goes here
echo "the line number we refer to is $line";
```

the output will be:

```
the line number we refer to is 3
```

[Run the example in your browser](http://ideone.com/Yl8uGB)

But I am afraid the answer to your question

> Is it possible in NetBeans to tag a line of code and refer to this line number dynamically?

is "**No**".

Comment: Good advise - thanks.
I had not thought about this solution but it practically solves my problem.